# How to use MediaStore

Tags: android, kotlin, audio-player, mediastore

I am making a small music player, I want to make the typical recyclerview that shows all the songs that are on the device. The problem is that I'm very new to using MediaStore and I don't really understand how it works. I have read the documentation and several articles, but I can't understand it very well. This is what I have done for the moment and I don't know if it is enough or if something is missing. I would be grateful if someone could show me how to achieve what I want to do.

**MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mBinding             : ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var mSongAdapter         : SongAdapter
    private lateinit var mLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager
    private var mSongs                        = listOf<Song>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mBinding.root)

        initSongs()
        initRecycler()

    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.i("Canciones:", mSongs.toString())
    }


    private fun initSongs() {
        GlobalScope.launch{
            mSongs = querySongs()

        }
    }

    private fun initRecycler() {
        mSongAdapter         = SongAdapter(mSongs)
        mLinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mBinding.rvCanciones.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = mLinearLayoutManager
            adapter       = mSongAdapter
        }
    }


    private suspend fun querySongs() : List<Song> {
        val songs = mutableListOf<Song>()

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE
            )

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                application.contentResolver.query(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null

                )?.use { cursor ->
                    val idColumn       = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
                    val nameColumn     =  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                    val durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
                    val sizeColum      = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE)

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                        val id       = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                        val name     = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
                        val duration = cursor.getFloat(durationColumn)
                        val size     = cursor.getString(sizeColum)

                        val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            id
                        )
                        val song = Song(contentUri, name, duration, size)
                        songs += song
                    }
                }
            } else {

                
            }
        }
        return songs
    }




}
```

**SONG DATA CLASS:**

```
data class Song(
    val uri      : Uri,
    val name     : String,
    val duration : Float,
    val size     : String
)
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @VivekGupta no, nothing just doesn't happen, what's missing to get what I want?

Comment: You did not tell what the cursor delivered you. How many songs? What is cursor.count()?

Comment: @blackapps It has not returned me any song, and I say that I do not know very well how it works, I have done it guided by the practical example of google, so I do not know if there is something wrong or I am missing something to make it work.

Comment: try to debug your code !!

Comment: @VivekGupta Okay, so it's fine? Nothing is missing and it should work? I want to know if it should work this way and it is a bug or something is missing.